# Sites for searching the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain.info

This is a general question, but what's the best way to search the blockchain? Blockchain.info lets you search by address, but it seems to be a side feature instead of its central purpose.

Are there other sites for searching Bitcoin transactions? I want to see all the transactions associated with a single address or to do other arbitrary types of searches?

Comment: Blockchain.info does let you view all transactions associated with an address. [Example.](https://blockchain.info/address/13DXzAXXZPCqUYBwcp3A47PZvP6Wxas9qE) Could you clarify why this doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks @NickODell. There's no specific purpose. Just looking for something interesting to build and contribute back to the Bitcoin community, but if tons of alternatives already exist, we prefer to find something else. Googling for ways to search Bitcoin hasn't yielded  many options, so we wanted to ask the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term for such a site is **block explorer** and there are many of them.  Among the top Google hits for "block explorer" are:

- http://blockexplorer.com
- http://blockchain.info
- http://biteasy.com
- http://blocktrail.com
- http://btc.blockr.io
- http://bkchain.org